# How to add style to the parent when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have two radio buttons and want when radio button is selected (checked) the parent box (`<div>`) to have these CSS styles:

```css
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
border-color: #28921f;
```

Here is my radio buttons with div`s:

```
<div class="delivery_option alternate_item">
    <input class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[0]" onchange="mydisplayudpate();updateCarrierSelectionAndGift();" id="delivery_option_0_1" value="6," checked="checked">
</div>

<div class="delivery_option item">
    <input class="delivery_option_radio" type="radio" name="delivery_option[0]" onchange="mydisplayudpate();updateCarrierSelectionAndGift();" id="delivery_option_0_0" value="7,">
</div>
```

I use jQuery for other functions about these buttons but i`m not sure how to add border and box shadow properly only when radio button is selected.

Comment: How about just adding a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the CSS declarations within a class and add/remove the class to the parent element of the radio buttons, as follows:

```css
.checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
  border-color: #28921f;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var $radios = $('input:radio');

$radios.change(function () {
    $radios.parent().removeClass('checked');
    $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/putot/1/edit)**.

In order to apply the effect once the page is loaded, you could add the class name to the correspond `div` parent element:

```
<div class="delivery_option alternate_item checked">
    <input type="radio" checked="checked">
</div>
```

Or do the same dynamically via JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('input:radio').filter(':checked').parent().addClass('checked');
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/putot/2/edit)**.